# Preg_grep pattern to get something between specific things

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-grep

file contains :

```
   <a href="site.com/" h="
   <a href="site3.com/" h="
```

so i want to echo all urls via pattern with preg_grep or preg_match ?

a pattern to get all between href=" and "

thanks !

Comment: Please add details as to what you have already tried and how it is not working.

Comment: my problem is the pattern to get all urls between <a href="betweenhere"

Comment: take a xml parser...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?page=1&tab=votes#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example how to use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
$html = '
    <a href="site.com/">link1</a>
    <a href="site3.com/">link2</a>
';


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($links as $link) {
    echo $link->getAttribute('href');
}
```

Look at another example at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#95894)